# Using a module to block shift key in access but when I write ap_DisableShift() in Immediate window I get this error "Compile Error Expected: ="

Tags: vba, ms-access

```vb
Option Compare Database

Function ap_DisableShift()
    'This function disable the shift at startup. This action causes
    'the Autoexec macro and Startup properties to always be executed.
    
    On Error GoTo errDisableShift
    
    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim prop        As DAO.Property
    Const conPropNotFound = 3270
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    'This next line disables the shift key on startup.
    db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = FALSE
    
    'The function is successful.
    Exit Function
    
    errDisableShift:
    'The first part of this error routine creates the "AllowByPassKey
    'property if it does not exist.
    If Err = conPropNotFound Then
        Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
            dbBoolean, False)
        db.Properties.Append prop
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Function        'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End Function

Function ap_EnableShift()
    'This function enables the SHIFT key at startup. This action causes
    'the Autoexec macro and the Startup properties to be bypassed
    'if the user holds down the SHIFT key when the user opens the database.
    
    On Error GoTo errEnableShift
    
    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim prop        As DAO.Property
    Const conPropNotFound = 3270
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    'This next line of code disables the SHIFT key on startup.
    db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = TRUE
    
    'function successful
    Exit Function
    
    errEnableShift:
    'The first part of this error routine creates the "AllowByPassKey
    'property if it does not exist.
    If Err = conPropNotFound Then
        Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
            dbBoolean, True)
        db.Properties.Append prop
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Function        'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: a) They should be `Subs`, not functions and b) only the boolean value changes, so you may as well pass it as an argument to a single method.

Comment: For the immediate, use `?ap_DisableShift()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Function DatabaseDisableShift()
    On Error GoTo FunctionError
    Dim CurrentDatabase As DAO.Database, DatabaseProperty As DAO.Property
    Const PropertyNotFound = 3270
    Set CurrentDatabase = CurrentDb()
    CurrentDatabase.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = False
    Exit Function
FunctionError:
    If Err = PropertyNotFound Then
        Set DatabaseProperty = _
        CurrentDatabase.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", dbBoolean, False)
        'Change to True, to enable shift.
        CurrentDatabase.Properties.Append DatabaseProperty
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```